# Minimal Sufficient Statistic for the distribution $U(-\theta, \theta)$

Tags: self-study, inference, sufficient-statistics

I need to find the sufficient statistic for the parameter $\theta$ for a uniform distribution $U(-\theta, \theta)$ for a sample of size $n$.

The joint density of the sample can be written as:

$f(x_1, x_2,..,x_n|\theta) = (\frac{1}{2\theta})^n,-\theta<x_i<\theta \text{ for all i = 1,2,3,..,n}$. I can express it as :

$f(x|\theta) = (\frac{1}{2\theta})^n \prod_{i=1}^{n} I_{(-\theta, \theta)}(x_i) = (\frac{1}{2\theta})^n  I_{(X_{(n)}, \infty)}(\theta)  I_{(-X_{(1)}, \infty)}(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^{n}I_{(-\infty,\infty)}$

Now, to prove a statistic, $ T(x)$, as minimally sufficient, we  need to prove that the ratio $\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)}$ to be constant as a function of $\theta$.

The ratio is computed as follows:

$\frac{f(x|\theta)}{f(y|\theta)} = \frac{(\frac{1}{2\theta})^n  I_{(X_{(n)}, \infty)}(\theta)  I_{(-X_{(1)}, \infty)}(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^{n}I_{(-\infty,\infty)}}{(\frac{1}{2\theta})^n  I_{(Y_{(n)}, \infty)}(\theta)  I_{(-Y_{(1)}, \infty)}(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^{n}I_{(-\infty,\infty)}}$

We can only get constant as a function of $\theta$ after substituting $X_{(n)} = Y_{(n)}$ and $X_{(1)} = Y_{(1)}$. Hence, $(X_{(1)}, X_{(1)})$ will be minimally sufficient. Please take a moment to review my steps and let me know where exactly I went wrong because the correct answer is shown as max of $|Xi|$.

Comment: Neither $X_{(n)}$ nor $(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is minimal sufficient: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116770/321264

Comment: It was max of $|Xi|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the range of your uniform distribution, you can see that $T(\mathbf{x}) = \max_{i=1,...,n} |X_i|$ is going to be the minimal sufficient statistic.  To demonstrate sufficiency formally, we note that the likelihood function reduces to:

$$\begin{align}
L_\mathbf{x}(\theta)
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \text{U}(x_i| -\theta, \theta) \\[6pt]
&= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2 \theta} \cdot \mathbb{I}(|x_i| \leqslant \theta) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2^n \theta^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{I}(|x_i| \leqslant \theta) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2^n \theta^n} \cdot \mathbb{I} \Big( \max_{i=1,...,n} |x_i| \leqslant \theta \Big) \\[6pt]
&= \frac{1}{2^n \theta^n} \cdot \mathbb{I}( T(\mathbf{x}) \leqslant \theta ). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Using the [Fisher–Neyman factorisation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic#Fisher%E2%80%93Neyman_factorization_theorem) this demonstrates that this statistic is sufficient.  Minimal sufficiency follows from the fact that there is no sufficient statistic from which this statistic cannot be obtained.

Comment: Specially the last line made everything clear to me. Plus +1 for that. This topic has been causing a lot of trouble for me since last week.

Comment: Hello @Ben, I was wondering about the completeness of this minimal sufficient estimator. So, here is what I am thinking. Since $|X|$ follows $U(0,\theta)$, I will have $\frac{|X|}{\theta}$ following $U(0,1)$ which means that it is ancillary. I once read that if a function of sufficient statistic is ancillary, then it cannot be complete. Hence, I will concluyde that this found minimally sufficient statistic will not be complete. Now, I was wondering whether there can be a situation when a family of distribution is not complete? If yes, is there exist a formal way to prove that.

Comment: @userNoOne: May I recommend that you pose that as a new question on the forum, and link back to this question for context.